# test if event handler is bound to an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to determine whether an element has a click handler, or a change handler, or any kind of event handler bound to it using jQuery?

Furthermore, is it possible to determine how many click handlers (or whatever kind of event handlers) it has for a given type of event, and what functions are in the event handlers?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can get this information from the data cache.

For example, log them to the console (firebug, ie8):

```
console.dir( $('#someElementId').data('events') );
```

or iterate them:

```
jQuery.each($('#someElementId').data('events'), function(i, event){

    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){

        console.log( handler.toString() );

    });

});
```

Another way is you can use the following [bookmarklet](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) but obviously this does not help at runtime.

Comment: does this only work for event handlers assigned with jQuery?

Comment: Yes Russ, that i true. But inline handlers are grim and deserve not to be shown!

Comment: Great answer. I just want to mention that this does not work for events attached with `live` (jQuery 1.4.4, FF).

Comment: @Atticus Correct because the delegated event using .live is attached to a container. (use .on rather than .live if using a modern jquery version)

Comment: Just a note: `$(element).data('events')` has been removed in jQuery 1.8.  For "debugging, you can use `$._data(element, 'events')`, but it's undocumented (and may change). http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, so question should be open with the jQuery 1.8? Or there is some other way do detect whether handler is attached?

Comment: @caligula: I don't know how it works in jQuery 1.8.  I'd say open a new question if it becomes a problem.

Comment: I tried this with an element that has a lot of handlers bound using `jQuery.on`, but the console says `undefined`! Any advice?

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde this was always an undocumented feature - I heard they may have removed it but I am not as close to jquery anymore. Remember that on binds to the container not the element itself.

Comment: @redsquare Thanks! Any other way to find what handlers were bound to a particular element?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde yes $._data(element, "events")

Comment: @redsquare Cool... trying that...

Comment: @gotqn do you expect everyone to update all their answers to keep in touch with new api's, notice the date of the answer.....

Comment: @gotqn - you should practise before preaching

Comment: @redsquare Of course I have expected. You can check hundreds of popular answers that have been constantly updated.

Comment: @gotqn the issue is actually StackOverflow and the lack of tech versioning

Comment: $._data($("#element")[0]).events

Comment: These solutions no longer work. You have to set boolean variables manually now.

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower The $._data() jQuery method still works in the latest version of jQuery. proof: https://codepen.io/alakatos/pen/MovJyG

Comment: You can also use function 'hasOwnProperty' with the event name.

Comment: this does not show anything on chrome for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events

Answer (score 134):

Killing off the binding when it does not exist yet is not the best solution but seems effective enough! The second time you ‘click’ you can know with certainty that it will not create a duplicate binding.

I therefore use die() or unbind() like this:

```
$("#someid").die("click").live("click",function(){...
```

or

```
$("#someid").unbind("click").bind("click",function(){...
```

or in recent jQuery versions:

```
$("#someid").off("click").on("click",function(){...
```

Comment: +1 very neat even though it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is the best way, and working way,, worked for me when other ways failed

Comment: For jQuery 1.7 and later use `.off("click")` instead of `.die()` or `.unbind()`

Comment: This is a band aid. It's a better idea to find out why your code is executing twice and fix that bug. Or figure out where else the bind is being called and prevent it.

Comment: Have to agree with @mattalxndr. At least use namespaces in such a case to avoid disabling events bound by unrelated code, like this:

    $("#someid").die("click.myPlugin").live("click.myPlugin",function(){...

Comment: I'd add that if you need to attach an event that only runs once and then removes itself, use the one() method. $("body").one("click",function(){ alert('test');});

Comment: @SJG: Is it a safe approach? What if in the middle of re-binding operation (after `off`, but yet before `on`) an event is raised? The handler is not going to intercept it, is it?

Answer (score 35):

I wrote a plugin called hasEventListener which exactly does that :

http://github.com/sebastien-p/jquery.hasEventListener

Hope this helps.

Comment: This plugin should be the accepted answer for anyone who is using jQuery.

Comment: Hopefully I can save someone else some time. hasEventListener doesn't work for `live` bound events.  (v1.0.5)

Comment: My hasEventListener plugin will be updated this week with now a full support for live and delegated events.

Comment: Why isn't this part of jQuery natively!!! good job +1

Comment: Like... any chance you can supply a 1.9 compatible version?

Answer (score 19):

This solution is no more supported since jQuery 1.8 as we can read on the blog here:

> $(element).data(“events”): This is now removed in 1.8, but you can still get to the
>   events data for debugging purposes via $._data(element, "events").
>   **Note that this is not a supported public interface; the actual data
>   structures may change incompatibly from version to version.**

So, you should unbind/rebind it or simply, use a boolean to determine if your event as been attached or not (which is in my opinion the best solution).

Comment: Any reason specified as to why it was removed?

Comment: Because it was used (.data) by jQuery to stock their internal events logic.

Comment: Which is what `$._data` does now?

Comment: I just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7788375/1049693), it explains everything :)

Comment: Where would you set the boolean?

Answer (score 16):

I think this might have updated with jQuery 1.9.*

I'm finding the this is the only thing that works for me at the moment:

```
$._data($("#yourElementID")[0]).events
```

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a very tiny plugin called "once" which do that:

```
$.fn.once = function(a, b) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).off(a).on(a,b);
    });
};
```

And simply:

```
$(element).once('click', function(){
});
```

Comment: This seems to be identical to jQuery's own `.one` -- http://api.jquery.com/one/ -- which has been around since v1.1. Yours just has an extra "c" added in.

Comment: @Luke I know this is old, but you're wrong. As I understand it, this is different in that jQuery.one() allows the event to run (trigger) ONLY once before self-removing. This .once() function simply ensures that any existing handler is removed before binding the replacement (which can then trigger multiple times). Perhaps the function name is the confusing part, and perhaps better thought of as $.fn.replaceOn()?

Answer (score 10):

For jQuery 1.9+

```
var eventListeners = $._data($('.classname')[0], "events");
```

I needed the `[0]` array literal.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that the hasEventListener plugin mentioned will handle custom events e.g.

```
var obj = {id:'test'};
$(obj).bind('custom', function(){
    alert('custom');
}).trigger('custom');

alert($(obj).hasEventListener('custom'));
```

Also, at least in jQuery 1.5 I think you need to be careful using $(target).data('events') because it returns differently for events that have been bound to objects as above.

You need to do something like:

```
var events = $(target).data("events");
if(typeof events === "function"){
   events = events.events;
}
```

I am using this sort of approach and it works but it feels a bit like I am at the mercy of jquery internals and that really I shouldn't be doing it!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need & quickly patched an existing code to be able to do something like this:

```
 if( $('.scroll').hasHandlers('mouseout') )  // could be click, or '*'...
 { 
   ... code ..
 }
```

It works for event delegation too:

```
 if ( $('#main').hasHandlers('click','.simple-search') )  ...
```

It is available here : [jquery-handler-toolkit.js](https://github.com/Inducido/jquery-handler-toolkit.js)

Answer (score 1):

With reference to [SJG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000418/132599) and from [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp)

> As of jQuery version 1.7, the off() method is the new replacement for the unbind(), die() and undelegate() methods. This method brings a lot of consistency to the API, and we recommend that you use this method, as it simplifies the jQuery code base.

This gives:

```
$("#someid").off("click").live("click",function(){...
```

or

```
$("#someid").off("click").bind("click",function(){...
```

Comment: bind is deprecated nowadays, so better use `$("#someid").off("click").on("click",function(){...`

Answer (score -6):

This works for me:
$('#profile1').attr('onclick')

Comment: it works only if a handler is attached via the "onclick" attribute. How about this case: `$('#profile1').click(function(){alert('')});`? `$('#profile1').attr('onclick')` returns `undefined`.