# Registering an Application to a Domain instead of a URI Scheme

Tags: c#

I see the example on how to register my own URI Scheme with the information available at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx) so I could link to something like "myApp://link" and my my application would open it.

I'm looking for something similar to that, but I'm trying to keep the link with the regular http scheme.. so instead of linking to "myApp://link" I could link to "http://myappdomain.com/link" and my app should open the link instead of the default option, but only for links at my domain! This way, they can load the webpage if they don't have my app installed, or they can open a window in the app if so.

Is there any possible way to do this? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not possible.  But try searching for your more general problem and you'll find things like:

[How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)

Comment: Since this question is tagged C#, I should mention that the iOS technique won't work consistently for Windows apps because some browsers (like Chrome) block redirects to custom schemes

Comment: You don't say? I'll have to see what I can do. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @c0nfus3d1 if you find a solution please let me know :)  I spent several hours on this a few weeks ago but gave up without success

Comment: I found the answer by UncleMiF @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330545/is-it-possible-to-open-custom-url-scheme-with-google-chrome

Comment: Suggests using a hidden IFRAME like `<iframe src="myApp://link1" />`