# HTTP-like treatment for custom URI scheme, possible?

Tags: apache, http, registry, uri

I defined a new URI scheme on my Windows system (following this thread: [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so))

I want the custom URI protocol to act like HTTP within Chrome/Firefox...

That is, I want: `myprotocol://localhost/test.html`

to act exactly like:
`http://localhost/test.html`

Is it possible, or does the browser insist on valid URI schemes, even if they are fully defined in the registry?

(This pertains to a local server and is required for personal application testing; I realise custom URI's are a bad standard and should not be used in production)

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to link a custom scheme to the browser of your choice. The challenge is to get the browser to treat your scheme exactly like `http://` as it cannot possibly know it has to speak HTTP to the target resource. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337525/3012385) suggests using an `<iframe/>` is a viable workaround.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you. I attempted that solution since you mentioned it. The iframe fails to load, it doesn't recognize the schema.