# How to simulate the clicking of a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have 2 links a1 and a2, and a2 is hidden.  When the user clicks on a1, I want to simulate the clicking of a2.  How can this be done with jQuery?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839363/simulating-a-click-in-jquery-javascript-on-a-link

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by *"simulate the clicking of a2"*.

Assuming that `a1` and `a2` are ID attributes, if you mean that you want to trigger the jQuery handler on that element, you can do this:

```
$("#a1").click(function(){ 
    $("#a2").trigger('click'); 
});
```

If you want to trigger it without bubbling the event or triggering the default behavior, do this:

```
$("#a1").click(function(){ 
    $("#a2").triggerHandler('click'); 
});
```

But if you wanted to actually visit the associated `href` location, you would need this:

```
$("#a1").click(function() { 
    window.location = $("#a2").attr('href'); 
});
```

or

```
$("#a1").click(function() { 
    window.location = document.getElementById('a2').href; 
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/trigger/
- http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#a1").click(function(){ $("#a2").click(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover your options as far as solutions go, but to improve your understanding of how jQuery works particular regarding event binding for clicks, I recommend looking over the [jQuery API documentation for click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/).