# Adding Javascript EventListener only if no other listener is present?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, greasemonkey

I'm a relative tyro in the Javascript programming arena, so please go easy on me.  :-)

I am trying to add an `eventListener` to various DOM elements on a page.  However, some of the elements I'm adding my event to already have an `eventListener`, and I don't want to supersede that one; I only want to add my event to an element that doesn't already have an event associated with it.

I've looked through a bunch of stuff relating to `addEventListener`, `event.StopPropagation`, event bubbling, and so forth, but haven't figured out any way to accomplish this yet.

Is there a way to detect other event listeners on a given element, or some other way to get where I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the on[event] property of that given element is set by using:

```
if (typeof(document.getElementById("element-id").onclick) == "undefined") {
  // event undefined
}

if (typeof(document.getElementById("element-id").onclick) == "function") {
  // event defined
}
```

Notice that this won't work if a javascript library such as jQuery were used to define the event (e.g. by using `$("#element-id").click()`). I'd recommend you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you can [handle events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) easily with it.

**edit:** uh, well, afaik it doesn't work if you're using addEventHandler too. It only works if you set your event by using `yourElement.onclick = anyFunction`

Comment: As it turns out, the event that I'm trying to detect is defined via jQuery (as a live() event).  I do have jQuery at my own disposal, but rummaging through the API info at the jQuery.com site, I still don't see anything about detecting pre-existing events, only info on how to bind my own events.

Comment: oh, in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery