# Add event to top of event stack using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery to add a blur event to a text box.  I would like my event to fire before any other existing events.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360655/jquery-event-handlers-always-execute-in-order-they-were-bound-any-way-around-th/2641047#2641047

Answer (score 0):

Not trivially.

The events are executed in the order they are bound. You could unbind all events, bind yourEvent, then rebind all events though.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
var fn = document.GetElementByID('x').clicked;
document.GetElementByID('x').clicked = function(){ 
  //action
  fn();
}
```

In Javascript the functions are function pointers.