# Binding event in jQuery to be executed always in the end

Tags: bind, jquery

Is there a way to bind events to some object, and ensure that one of those events will be executed always last?

```
  $('#something').bind('click', function () {
    // do something first
  });
  $('#something').bind('click', function () {
    // do this always last
  });  
  $('#something').bind('click', function () {
    // do this after first one
  });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

May not be that good approach, but I found it pretty useful. You can use `setTimeout` without any parameter.

```
$('#something').bind('click', function () {

  setTimeout(function(){
    // This will always execute at last
    // Write your code here.
  });
});
```

Basically `setTimeout()` re-queues the function at the end of the execution queue.

Comment: This is actually an extremely useful quirk. I wonder if it can be relied upon cross browser?

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that this works in all browsers. I believe it is actually how jQuery processes events rather than how the browser processes events, regardless it works in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE 11, and IE 80 (whatever they call it these days). Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpcqhsx1/

Answer (score 1):

You could bind all the handlers in one go:

```
$('#something').click(function () {
    first();
    second();
    third();
});
```

This comes with the added bonus of being a bit more efficient/lightweight than binding 3 separate listeners.

Comment: and easier to maintain instead of defining several in different places (yuck! shame on you!)

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how many events will be bound to #something element. It can be from 1 to x and i want to ensure that  one specific will be executed always at the end, no matter in which order events are bound

Comment: @Goran: _"The problem is that i don't know how many events will be bound to #something element."_ Why not? Event handlers should really be independent of each other. At any rate, it's generally a good idea to minimize the number of listeners.

Comment: Because i'm building complex web application, and i want to handle one event on all <select> elements i'm using in whole web application. That handler need to be triggered last, because i want to allow other handlers to be bound to the same element. Those events can change any property of that element. After all other events are executed i need to execute my handler, which will do stuff it needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: this can be useful but may not work as OP's question requires. The handler that fires on `one` does not get attached to the end of the current handler queue, it only runs on subsequent events.**

For future readers, you can achieve this by proxying the handler using `one()`.

```
$('.some-class').on('anevent', function(evt) {
    $(this).one(evt.type, function(evt) {
        //this code will fire after all other handlers for this event, except others that are proxied the same way
        console.log(evtO == evt, 'same event');
        if (evt.isDefaultPrevented())//can check signals to see whether you should still handle this event
            return;
        //do stuff last
    });
})
```

Later on somewhere else:

```
$('.some-class').on('anevent', function(evt) {
    //do stuff first
    evt.preventDefault();//can signal to prevent the proxied function. could use evt.stopPropagation() instead
})
```

The one caveat is that if a later handler uses a `return false;` or `stopImmediatePropagation()`, the function bound with `one()` will fire *first* the next time that event occurs, unless you explicitly unbind it somehow.