# How to make sure an event handler is executed after the same event handler is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Essentially, this is my code:

```js
$('#press').click(function() { alert('First') });
$('#press').click(function() { alert('Second') });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="press">press</button>
```

How can I make sure if the second event handler-`$('#press').click(secondFunction);` is executed only after the first event handler-`$('#press').click(firstFunction);` is finished?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - Make sure event handler is last to be executed in chain of handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150841/jquery-make-sure-event-handler-is-last-to-be-executed-in-chain-of-handlers)

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make sure the second event handler is executed only after the first event handler is finished?

Using your current pattern you can't. However you could call them sequentially inside a single event handler, like this:

```js
var firstFunction = function() { alert('First') };
var secondFunction = function() { alert('Second') };
$('#press').click(function() {
  firstFunction();
  secondFunction();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="press">press</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case I can't join together those events nor the functions.

Comment: Why is that? If you can provide function references then this should be possible.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to make it more readable, therefore I put the function references. :) If it gives a confusion, let me edit my snipped code then.

Answer (score 2):

Use callbacks as shown below

```js
var firstFunction = function(callback) {
  alert('First');
  callback();
};
var secondFunction = function() {
  alert('Second')
};

$('#press').click(function() {
  firstFunction(secondFunction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="press">press</button>
```