# Run my jQuery function before/after plugin for the same event listener?

Tags: jquery

Im using a jQuery plugin and separately im writing my own jQuery which is initialise on dom ready. If both the plugin and my code do something on an event (say a div is clicked) how can I tell which code is run first?

Also, is there a way I specify which code I want to run first? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to order events bound with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery)

Comment: I would say that its not a duplicate as I dont want to edit the plugin code at all if possible.

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9302927/1180424)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API says `Event handlers bound to an element are called in the same order that they were bound.` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: And there's no way of overriding this? Thanks

Comment: I don't know a way to do so, posts linked by Jon and jb10210 might help though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery & http://stackoverflow.com/q/9302927/1180424

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can** override the event handlers order by using some methods like **pop**, **unshift**, **"push"** and **"shift"** on the event handlers array and....

For example, according to @roasted answer >> move last event handler to top of the list:

```
var myH = $._data( $(".myclass")[0], "events" ).click.pop();
$._data( $(".myclass")[0], "events" ).click.unshift(myH);

console.log($._data( $(".myclass")[0], "events" ).click);
```

I recommend you to visit **[this question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376305/forcing-to-run-a-custom-function-befor-run-the-assigned-event-handlers-of-an-ele).**