# Forcing to run a custom function befor run the assigned event handlers of an element

Tags: jquery

Imagine a jQuery plugin insert an element (such as an image) to the page and the image has an event handler for Click event. for example when i click the image open one popup div.

An other hand i wrote a function in my page. for example a function for slow fade an textbox (input tag).

So we have:

- A jquery plugin
- An image added by the jquery plugin -->>> id ="MyImage"
- Click event of image causes --->> popup a div
- An input tag --->> id="MyInput"
- My Function that hide the input --->> hideSlowInput()

**Important note:** i don't want change the plugin. i want override the event handler of the image without change the plugin.

**Edit:** i have not codes to open the popupdiv, i just start the plugin in the $(document).ready

**Now, how can i force to open popup div after running my function every time i click the image???**

Comment: It would be simpler if you post some code to understand what you are looking for? Delegate event, triggering or what...

Comment: I have a complicated sample in my big project, So I've simplified it by a mental example.

Comment: do you want to **run a custom function on click of the image before its click event handler, which is bound on image creation,  runs**?

Comment: @Ejay, yes exactly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following @roasted's answer**

**I forced old event handlers to run as callback of new event handler:**

[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/8qXXH/)

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
    alert(1);
});

$('#myBtn').click(function(){
    alert(2);
});

$('#myBtn').click(function(){
    alert(3);
});

$('#myBtn').click(function(evt){
    alert(4);
});

//------Adding A Custom Function Befor All Click Event Handlers And Forcing Theme Run As Callback Of The Custom Function--------

console.clear();
var objEvents=jQuery.extend(true, {}, $._data( $("#myBtn")[0], "events" ));
$('#myBtn').unbind('click');

var callEventHandlers=function(myEventName,myEvents){
        $.each(myEvents, function(i, event) {
            if(i==myEventName){
                $.each(event, function(j, h) {
                  //  console.log(h.handler.toString());
                    h.handler.call()
                });
            }
        });
}

$('#myBtn').click(function(evt){
    $(this).fadeOut(3000,function(){callEventHandlers('click',objEvents)});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Following @Ejay's comment**

This is basically not possible, at least, not publicly supported in documentation {nothing i can find...}

But if the plugin you are talking about using jquery to bind the open popup div handler, you can try this:

```
//declare your function
function myfunction(){
   alert('ok');
}
//bind click handler to image with class 'myclass'
$('.myclass').click(myfunction);

//set this handler in first with keeping other already bound events
var myH = $._data( $(".myclass")[0], "events" ).click.pop();
$._data( $(".myclass")[0], "events" ).click.unshift(myH);
```

If there is no other click handler, you could just reverse order:

```
[].reverse.call($._data($('.myclass')[0]).events.click);
```

See a generic demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AjJac/)

Comment: your answer is great and very useful for me. but i want a more advanced version of your answer. finally i want second event handler be as callback of the first event handler. i wrote in the question about a function for SLOW FADE. so i want run second event handler after fade event finished. i want each event run when previous event completely finished.

Answer (score 0):

not clear what you  actually need here (unless you provide your related codes) but i think you need a delegated click event here..

since the image is added dynamically you need to use on delegated event..

```
 $(document).on('click','#MyImage',function(){
     alert('clicked image');
     //codes to open your popopdiv
 });
```

NOTE: since a image is added , you might end up having same IDS for images(unless you are adding just one image) , which is invalid.. ID should always be unique... it will be better if you can add images with class instead of id... and use class selector `.Myimage`..and delegating it to the closest statis parent container is better than the document itself..

Comment: my image have the class. i have not the codes to open popupdiv. the codes are wrote in the plugin and they  click event handler assignd to the image in the plugin. i just started the plugin in the $(document).ready.