# How to bind an event before an already existing one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

`$(element).data("events")` gives me a list of all the events for `element`. Considering that *I need to bind an event and have it fire before another one already bound to it*, how can I accomplish that?

I have thought of unshifting an event to the list returned from `$(element).data("events").myevent`, but I'm guessing that's not the right approach.

Thank you.

Comment: put second one inside first :-)

Comment: In a previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360655/jquery-event-handlers-always-execute-in-order-they-were-bound-any-way-around-t) your proposed method was the accepted answer. Seems neat and clean enough.

Comment: @user1090190 looks like a nice approach, thank you. Extracting behavior is what I need for modularity purposes.

Comment: @josemota the answer u1090190 pointed out is now 2 years old. Since then jQuery has acquired [jQuery.Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) - "a multi-purpose callbacks list object that provides a powerful way to manage callback lists". You might consider this as an alternative approach to meeting your ends.