# Override javascript click event one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to replace the default action of an click event for all anchors in a webpage.
When I use this piece of code:

```
<html> <head> <script>     
var list=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var isChecked = false;

function load () {    
    for (i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        var old = (list[i].onclick) ? list[i].onclick : function () {}; 
        list[i].onclick = function () {                 
        if( !isChecked)
        {
            test(); 
            old();
        }
        else
            old();
        };  
    }
}    
function test() {
    alert("new action");
    isChecked = true;
}     
</script> </head> 
<body onload="load();">     
<a id="nr_1" onClick="alert('test');"> Anchor 1 </A>
<a id="nr_2" onClick="alert('test2');"> Anchor 2 </A>      
</body> </html>
```

When I click an anchor I get the alert out of the test function and then the default function of the second anchor (even when I click the first anchor). When I then again click one of the two anchors I always get the Alert from the second anchor. 
How do I put the original onclick functions back for each anchor element? When someone has an solution in jquery I would be glad as well.

**EDIT**

I was succesfull using this code:

```
function load()
{
$('a').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('a').click(function(e){
    if($(this).attr('disabled'))
    {
    alert("new");
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('a').removeAttr("disabled");  
    this.click();
    }
});
}
```

On loading of the page this function is called giving all anchor elements a "disabled" attribute. After clicking the element the e.preventDefault() function disables the inline onclick function. Then I remove the "disabled" attribute and call the click function of the element again. because now the element doesn't have a "disabled" attribute only the default function is performed. I'm still open for "more elegant" solutions to this problem, but for now I'm a happy camper!

Comment: try this: onClick="alert('test'); return false;" it should stop the link from navigating and thus stay on the same page and have your variable values

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery you can combine a one-time handler with a persistent handler:

Documentation for [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8gmN/

Sample HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="click" value="click" />
```

​
Sample JavaScript:

```
button.one('click', function () {
  console.log('one time function fired');  
});

button.on('click', function () {
  console.log('persistent function fired');  
});
```

​

Comment: As a side note, I am not sure how jQuery will order these two events. If order is important, you may want to investigate this. Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360655/jquery-event-handlers-always-execute-in-order-they-were-bound-any-way-around-t

Comment: For additional information I am not able to edit the HTML code and the anchor tags have an existing onclick function (as inline attribute)

Comment: then just use the .one() handler.