# How to bind, unbind and rebind (click) events in JQuery

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

After asking the same question 2 weeks ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729681/jquery-rebind-disable-events-for-a-specific-time-then-rebind-them), I finally found "the" solution. This is why I am answering my own question. ;)

**HOW TO BIND, UNBIND AND REBIND EVENTS IN JQUERY?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery rebind() disable events for a specific time, then rebind them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729681/jquery-rebind-disable-events-for-a-specific-time-then-rebind-them)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

And THIS is the perfect solution. (At least for me.)

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#button', function(){
    $(this).after('<span> hello</span>');
    $('span').fadeOut(1000);
});

$('a#toggle').toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).text('rebind');
        $('a#button').on('click.disabled', false);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).text('unbind');
        $('a#button').off('click.disabled');
    }
);
```

".on()" does it. NOTE: It is important to bind the event like you can see on line one! It does not work with .click() or …!

See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)!

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RAcGD/) to try it and experiment with it!

Enjoy!

Comment: Why did you repost it if you already answered it on your original question?

Comment: I guess because the other solution is also nice and useful! (Updated the old post)

Comment: Great answer! This certainly helped me temporarily disable a button's click event. And, for additional emphasis, the context of the click event should be how it is shown in the above answer!

Comment: Question: why does this work? Are we enabling/disabling a 'disabled' property on the native click event?

Comment: Important! For anyone looking into this, the `.toggle()` method was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. ([Source - jQuery.com](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/))

Answer (score 3):

A simpler and short solution is to add a class to the object if you want to unbind it then remove this class to rebind ex;

```
$('#button').click( function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('unbinded')) return;
   //Do somthing
 });

$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('#button').toggleClass('unbinded');
 });
```