# jQuery unbind keypress event and rebind after successful ajax-call

Tags: jquery, keypress

I'm currently developing a small comment system with ajax. I want to unbind the keypress event when the enter key is pressed (to avoid duplicate comments) and rebind it after a successful ajax-call.

```
jQuery(".commentDiv textarea").keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13  && !event.shiftKey) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var textarea = jQuery(this);
        var comment = jQuery.trim(textarea.val());

        if (!comment.length) {
            alert("No valid comment.");
            return false;
        }
        var the_data =
        {
            ...
        };
        textarea.attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
        textarea.val("Saving comment. Please wait...");
        textarea.off('keypress.disabled');
        // or textarea.unbind('keypress'); which also works

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, the_data, function(sp_response) {
            textarea.attr( "disabled", false);
            textarea.val("");
            textarea.on('keypress.disabled', false); // not working
        });
    }
});
```

`keypress.disabled` code is taken from [How to bind, unbind and rebind (click) events in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940591/how-to-bind-unbind-and-rebind-click-events-in-jquery).

**What is the easiest way to rebind the keypress event to the element?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding and unbind simply use a flag to skip un-wanted execution. Set the variable value at the start of event and reset it on post callback to get ready for next event.

```
var isAlreadyPressed = false;
jQuery(".commentDiv textarea").keypress(function(event) {
   if(isAlreadyPressed) return;
   isAlreadyPressed = true;    
...
...

 jQuery.post(ajaxurl, the_data, function(sp_response) {
           isAlreadyPressed = false;
           //your code here
 });
```

Comment: This is way easier than my approach. Thanks!