# Make a div clickable only one times

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, clickable

I have a function that when a div is click, an animation is proceed.
and I want that the user is able to click only one times for not load that animation at every click. Maybe a div clickable one time or a if in the function but I'm not that good in code :)

this is the code

```
$(function() {    
    $('#valerie').click(function() {

        $('.logo').animate({
            'left': 3 + '%'
        }, 900);
        $('#title2').animate({
            'font-size': 40 + 'px',
            'top': 42 + '%'
        }, 900);
        $('body').css({
            'overflow': "auto"
        }, 20);
    });
});
```

Comment: i have two div side by side, if you click on one, it take 90% of the page and the other 10%. So if i click on the left div for exemple it will take 90% of the page but if i click on the right div after and then want to return on the left div. I won't be able to do it with the ".one" jquery command you tell me. Thanks for your quick answer !

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

```
$('#valerie').one('click', function() {
    $('.logo').animate({'left':  3    + '%'},900);
    $('#title2').animate({'font-size': 40 + 'px','top': 42 + '%'},900);
    $('body').css({'overflow': "auto" },20);
});
```

Comment: thanks, it resolve the first step of my problem.

i have two div side by side, if you click on one, it take 90% of the page and the other 10%. So if i click on the left div for exemple it will take 90% of the page but if i click on the right div after and then want to return on the left div. I won't be able to do it with the ".one" jquery command you tell me.

Thanks for your quick answer !

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to do. This fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/td6a8pwu/ may help you. @SteveD

Answer (score 1):

You can try .off(event) after your logic on that event

```
$('#valerie').on('click', function () {
        $('.logo').animate({
            'left': 3 + '%'
        }, 900);
        $('#title2').animate({
            'font-size': 40 + 'px',
            'top': 42 + '%'
        }, 900);
        $('body').css({
            'overflow': "auto"
        }, 20);

        $(this).off(event);
    });
```

Comment: how to rebind if needed?

Comment: you can check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940591/how-to-bind-unbind-and-rebind-click-events-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `one()` method as @Azim suggest, or you can use `stop()` if you want to make the animation ends after new animation is request:

```
$('#valerie').on('click', function() {

    $('.logo').stop().animate({
        'left': 3 + '%'
    }, 900);
    $('#title2').stop().animate({
        'font-size': 40 + 'px',
        'top': 42 + '%'
    }, 900);
    $('body').css({
        'overflow': "auto"
    }, 20);


});
```

This is because I am not sure that you need only once the animation or you need to avoid the multiple animations after ends.

Comment: i want to avoid the mutiple animation !

Comment: According to your comment in the @Azim answer, your solution is this answer. Use `stop()` to stop the animation in every click that the animation hasn't finish.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery one()

```
$('#valerie').one('click', function() {

})
```

Comment: same answers like @Azim 17 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

There is a .one method in jquery for one time click event.

```
$('#valerie').one('click', function() {

    $('.logo').animate({
        'left': 3 + '%'
    }, 900);
    $('#title2').animate({
        'font-size': 40 + 'px',
        'top': 42 + '%'
    }, 900);
    $('body').css({
        'overflow': "auto"
    }, 20);

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `:animated`:

```
$('#valerie').click(function() {
    if($(':animated').length || $('body').css('overflow') === "auto"){// <---add this 
        return; 
    }  
    $('.logo').animate({'left':  3    + '%'},900);
    $('#title2').animate({'font-size': 40 + 'px','top': 42 + '%'},900);
    $('body').css({'overflow': "auto" },20);
});
```