# Sorting with jqGrid Inline editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there any direct way to sort the data on `jqGrid` at client side with inline editing?
It does not **sort** data when the row is editable even if the row header is clicked.

Comment: Do you have the column set as sortable?

Comment: Yes. It is set to true. It works fine if it is not editable. For inline editing I made custom method. Can we avoid this custom method? Do we have any direct way?

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure on what you are asking, are you trying to sort while editing? Or after you edit?

Comment: My jqGrid is in inline edit mode. i.e., one of the rows in my grid is always editable. I want to sort the data on click of header of the grid when that row is still editable

Comment: You ALWAYS have a row in edit mode? is that built in or something you customized?

Comment: @PranitG: Setting of all rows of grid in editing mode is very bad way usage of grid. Typically one should use cell editing mode instead or row editing with activating of editing on row select (in `onSelectRow` callback). I don't know any practical example when activating of all rows of grid in editing mode has real and practical sense. Probably you can describe and example and the describe the advantages of this.

Comment: @Oleg: At a given point of time, I have only single row editable(not all). Similar to one mentioned in example. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, I found the following algorithm:

1. Catch the header click event. e.g. ('th').click(function(){})
2. Save the the row data which is in edit mode using `saveRow` when this event occurs
3. Identify the header which is clicked.
4. Sort grid data with that header in    ascending or descending order. 
   like 
   `$('#dataGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', ({ data: list, sortname: columnHeader, sortorder: 'asc',rowNum: list.length })).trigger('reloadGrid');`
5. Make the selected row editable again. `editRow` can be used for this.

**Note:** Steps 2 to 5 should be executed in event at steps 1 (header click event)

Comment: If you read my answer you will agree that your answer contains many restrictions when it works and contains other decisions like saving editing row without asking the user. Is it not easier just to display some warning to user which informs that the user have to save or discard the editing to be able to sort?

Answer (score 3):

Grid can't be sort if some line is editing. I think that the reason of your question is a misunderstanding about how inline editing works and how sorting works.

At the beginning of editing the original data from the editing row will be saved in internal parameter `savedRow` array. In any time the user can revert the current modifications back to original state or save the current values in the grid. If `keys: true` option of inline editing is enabled then the user can use <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys to revert/save the changes of the current row. It is permitted that multiple rows could be in the same time in editing mode and the user could save some rows and some other revert.

The sorting of grid means **rebuilding of full grid content** applying of the current filter from internal `postData` parameter. **jqGrid** supports *multiple pages*. Sorting of grid means always the sorting of optionally filtered *over all data of the grid*. After sorting if should be displayed only the current page based on the value of `page` parameter.

To sort the grid which is in editing mode one would need to decide what should be done with currently editing rows. Neither discarding of current changes nor saving could be good solution in common case. Even if one would try first to save the current editing data (old state and current state) then sort the data and later start editing one more time it could not work in common case. It could be many problems of implementation such scenario

1. the current editing row could be on another page, which is not visible now
2. the data could be changed now. So filling `savedRow` array with old data could be wrong and the current editing data could be also wrong.
3. the current editing row could be deleted from another user. So it could not exist in new grid content.
4. if we decide to save data before sorting if could be some validation errors or concurrency errors during saving. So one need to ask user first to solve all the conflicts before saving could take place.

   ...

So to sort grid which is in editing mode is not easy. The implementation way could depend on the project requirements. Because of described above problems (and many other which I didn't mention) jqGrid just test whether internal `savedRow` array (used to save old state of row before editing started) is empty or not. If the `savedRow` array is not empty then there are some row or cell (in case of sell editing mode) which is editing now. In the case any click on the corresponding column header will be ignored and no sorting is done.

Comment: I was searching for the suitable answer that is why did not reply. I replied my answer and accepted it. Because of your answer/hint, I could go further and I got assured that there is no direct way to sort grid data when it is inline editing. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem --not being able to sort if any row is in edit mode.  In my case it didn't matter what the state of the user edits were.   My grid is clientSide and there is a save button on the page the user's clicks to submit the changes.

I did some digging around and found a solution that works for me.  I hope it helps others.  Basically what I did was reorder the click events on the column headings so that mine was first.  Then in my click event I call saveRows.

Here is a piece of code I got from another thread [here about reordering events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360655/jquery-event-handlers-always-execute-in-order-they-were-bound-any-way-around-t):

```
        $.fn.bindUp = function(name, fn) {
        // bind as you normally would
        // don't want to miss out on any jQuery magic
        this.on(name, fn);

        // Thanks to a comment by @Martin, adding support for
        // namespaced events too.
        this.each(function() {
            var handlers = $._data(this, 'events')[name.split('.')[0]];
            // take out the handler we just inserted from the end
            var handler = handlers.pop();
            // move it at the beginning
            handlers.splice(0, 0, handler);
        });
    };
```

Then in my code I add a handler to save the rows:

```
        $("th.ui-th-column", $("#pacPaymenReviewGridNEW")[0].grid.hDiv).bindUp('click', function(e) {
        var $th = $(e.currentTarget).closest("th");
        if ($th.length > 0) {
            pacTransferFundMaint.saveRowsById('#pacPaymenReviewGridNEW');
        }
    });
```