# How to check if the radio buttons has already bound with a "change" event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate, jquery-events

If I have radio buttons :

```
<input id="y0" type="radio" name="myRadioBtns" value="a" checked> <label for="y0"></label>
<input id="y1" type="radio" name="myRadioBtns" value="b">  <label for="y1"></label>
<input id="y2" type="radio" name="myRadioBtns" value="c">  <label for="y2"></label>
```

The radio buttons may have already bound a change event handler like following:

```
$('input[name='myRadioBtns']').change(function() {
  //EVENT HANDLER
});
```

I need to check if the radio buttons have already bound with a "change" event handler or not.

My question is **How to check if the radio buttons has already bound with a "change" event handler**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element should help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test whether a change event has already been bound before you bind another one, use this:

```
var $el = $('input[name='myRadioBtns']');

if( ! ($el.data('events') && $el.data('events').change) ) {

   $el.change(function() {
       //EVENT HANDLER
   });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I come with another problem which is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334947/how-to-make-sure-only-one-event-handler-get-called-when-select-radio-buttons-very

Answer (score 2):

You can get bound events with:

```
.data('events')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I come with another problem which is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334947/how-to-make-sure-only-one-event-handler-get-called-when-select-radio-buttons-very

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can bind multiple namespaced change events that each do different things.  For example if you were writing a jQuery plugin that needs to bind events to elements, but not remove any existing events that might already be set on the page.

Whenever I'm writing a jQuery plugin I make sure all events are bound like this:

```
    $(":checkbox").on("change.myNamespace", function(){
        //Do Stuff - this won't replace existing change events on checkboxes!
    });
```