# Trying to unbind events on iPad2 with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Bit of background, we are creating an html5 'app' for the iPad, which has everything contained in a single page, and all the content is dynamic.

I  have a dynamically generated anchor, which then has a click event bound to it as so:

```
 $j(toElement).find(".moveSlideUp").bind('click', addSlideToPresentation_click);
```

This all works fine, however the problem is that once we navigate away from that page/section, and navigate back to it, the event handler is bound a second time, and thus fires twice (or 3 or 4 times etc...).

I have tried calling unbind before binding, but this makes no difference - any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind handler in the same context which when is reloaded releases your handler as well. Or check if handler is already bound:

[jquery check if event exists on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element)

[test if event handler is bound to an element in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for that! Ended up just rewriting it with a onClick attrib!