# What's the difference between jQuery.data and jQuery._data ( underscore data )?

Tags: javascript, jquery

While going through the source, I noticed that 'toggle' supposedly uses `jQuery._data` to store the state of the element. I examined the `jQuery.cache` object in chrome and found that the element's data object had yet another object under it prepended by the word jQuery with a number that I'm guessing uniquely identifies it. However, I saw no data regarding the state of the element. Simply `{olddisplay: 'block'}`. Any clues as to the purpose of jQuery._data and how it works per se?

I've been staring at the source all day .... please don't tell me to view the source. My eyes and brain will thank you.

Comment: Oftentimes you'll see variables and functions (or object methods/properties) that are meant to be handled as *private* or some other special meaning have a preprended character like `_` to group them together by scope or application. In jQuery, it's merely meant as *treat this as private to the object*, ie, **Don't access externally.**

Answer (score 55, accepted):

jQuery uses _data in order to set the 'pvt' flag for data it stores on the object.  The `pvt` is used so that when you request public data from the object, pvt data is not returned.  This is to keep jQuery's internal use of the `.data()` mechanism (like what toggle does) from effecting the public use of `.data()`.

You can see this declaration in the jQuery source:

```
// For internal use only.
_data: function( elem, name, data ) {
    return jQuery.data( elem, name, data, true );
},
```

Which just calls `jQuery.data` and forces the fourth parameter (which is privacy) to be true.  When retrieving data, if the `pvt` flag is set, then it is retrieved in a slightly different way.  The public interfaces to `.data()` do not expose the `pvt` flag.

You can see an example of `pvt` handling here in this part of `jQuery.data()`:

```
// An object can be passed to jQuery.data instead of a key/value pair; this gets
// shallow copied over onto the existing cache
if ( typeof name === "object" || typeof name === "function" ) {
    if ( pvt ) {
        cache[ id ][ internalKey ] = jQuery.extend(cache[ id ][ internalKey ], name);
    } else {
        cache[ id ] = jQuery.extend(cache[ id ], name);
    }
}
```

and then later in that same function, this comment is pretty descriptive:

```
// Internal jQuery data is stored in a separate object inside the object's data
// cache in order to avoid key collisions between internal data and user-defined
// data
if ( pvt ) {
    if ( !thisCache[ internalKey ] ) {
        thisCache[ internalKey ] = {};
    }
    thisCache = thisCache[ internalKey ];
}
```

Comment: Great description. Thank you so much for your answer!