# How to see where all events are bound for elements on a page?

Tags: jquery, events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing functions bound to event handlers with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388030/accessing-functions-bound-to-event-handlers-with-jquery)

I have a around 10 jQuery plugins on my page. It seems that some elements have two events attached to it because one ajax call let say when .change() happen in a textbox fires two post calls. Is there in Firebug, or in some other tool or browser than Firefox (I did not find one) where you can see events that are attached to a page's elements?

Comment: If it's jQuery, `jQuery(elem).data('events');` or `$._data($(elem).get(0), "events")` used to work, not sure about the latest version though. On the other hand 9 of those plugins are probably for something you could easily do with a few lines of code yourself ?

Comment: …but this questions title is better.

Comment: @feeela, yes indeed, the referenced question's title is little more than gobbledygook.

Comment: @adeneo, your second example works in jQuery 1.9+ as of this time. http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#data-events-.

Also relevant is an explanation of the "private" $._data method.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788353/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-data-and-jquery-data-underscore-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [Eventbug](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug), an extension to Firebug, which

> lists all of the event handlers on the page grouped by event type

Comment: nice plugin, but if one uses a JS lib (I tested with jQuery), this plugin will only render useless information, as it prints the jQuery internals, instead of the of the function passed as event handler.