# Select All Elements that do not have a binding to a given function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I assign a function to a variable *foo*, is there a way to select all elements that do not have a binding to *foo* given that they are assigned via a structure like `$('.elementsWithClass').click(foo)`?

My motivation here is we have ajax requests replacing parts of the DOM, and I need an easy way  to rebind event handlers that is not based on .live/.on as we are controlling event bubbling in some parts of the application.

Comment: duplicate of [test if event handler is bound to an element in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the motivation for doing this, since they are assigned with `$(".elementsWithClass").click(foo)`, you should just reselect them after the DOM has been updated.

```
$("#container").load("/new/content.html", function() {
    $(this).find(".elementSWithClass").click(foo);
});
```

Since they need to be rebound, that must mean they've been replaced, which means it won't do any good to select them based on if they have a handler.

Comment: I would suggest unbinding the click even before binding it again, as there could be elements sill on the page that were previously bound.  Or prevent bubbling inside of foo.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/QAyB5/.  If you uncomment the unbind line, you'll only get a single line written to the console (single function call) per click.  When it is commented, you'll get a line for each click binding.

Comment: @Gromer: It depends on how the DOM is being replaced. Given my example, everything inside `#container` is being replaced, so there's no need to manually unbind. The binding is only happening inside `#container`. If we unbind from `document`, we may be unbinding some that shouldn't be.

Comment: Ahh, good point, since the container content is getting *replaced*.  Good call, sir!

Comment: @Gromer: Yes, but your point is very valid if the new content is being appended along side other elements that are already bound.