# How to check if element has click handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [test if event handler is bound to an element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery)

Tried to do the following (link is jQuery object of 'a' tag):

```
 link.data("events") //undefined even if link has event handlers
 jQuery.data(link, 'events') //undefined always also
 jQuery._data(link, 'events') //undefined always also
```

using jquery-1.8.3

So, how to check if element has click handler?

Comment: How did you assign the click handler?

Comment: are you sure link is being selected correctly

Comment: Handlers assigned with link.click(...some function...) several times, because I cant check if it already exist. And so that handlers executed several times

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `jQuery._data` to check for events. The first argument should be a reference to the HTML element, not the jQuery object.

```
var ev = $._data(element, 'events');
if(ev && ev.click) alert('click bound');
```

Sample below.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        // NOTE: this below is refering to the HTML element, NOT the jQuery element
        var ev = $._data(this, 'events');
        if(ev && ev.click) alert('click bound to this button');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Click me to check for click handlers</button>
```

Also note that this method for checking events will only work when the event is bound via jQuery. If the event is bound via `element.attachEventListener`, `element.onclick`, `<a onclick="doStuff()">` or any other non jQuery way, this will not work. If you're fitting into this boat, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22841712/1090190).

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower Can you elaborate? This is working for me on jQuery versions 2.1.3 and 1.11.0.

Comment: My apologies, it was an error on my part. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @Ionian316 `undefined == false` so `if(ev && ev.click)` does the same thing.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus Yes, I was in the process of editing my comment, but got timed out. What I wanted to say was that if you want to check to see if an event handler has been bound before binding one, you can use `if (typeof ev === "undefined" || !ev.click) element.click(clickEventHandler);`.