# How to identify if element has a registered event Handler or not

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video, dom-events

Its not like this question has not been asked anywhere.
But I need some specific implementation of the mentioned problem. I need to know if the 'video' tag has registered event handler or not in the application. I tried it using the jQuery methods but it simply does not work. I am new to jQuery, so may be I am doing it in a wrong way. Here is what I referred [How to check if element has click handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072042/how-to-check-if-element-has-click-handler)

```
var ev = $._data(element, 'events');
```

I implemented it like this

```
var ev = $._data($('video')[0], 'volumechange');
```

where `$('video')[0]` holds the HTML video tag.

The above query always returns

> unidentified

So, where am I going wrong?
My application has an event handler registered to it

```
<script>
video.addEventListener('volumechange', handleVideoEvent, false);
</script>
```

I expect

```
var ev = $._data($('video')[0], 'volumechange');
```

to return

`handleVideoEvent` object.

And moreover is jQuery the only way to get the registered event handlers.
Is there a way in Javascript itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events

Comment: http://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/javascript/2012/interacting-with-html5-video-players/

Comment: Thanks Vaibs, but I think you got my question wrong. I don't need support to addeventlisteners to video. instead I need help to find out if an event has a registered event listener or not.