# jquery if click it´s possible

Tags: jquery, onclick

It's possible do something as if click in jquery the same as conditional in php, in many cases I need detect if click in one div and if click no execute another function no see many things about this and we know if it's possible finally

Some as this

```
if ($("#selecter").click(function(){});)
```

Comment: This [`.click()` function](http://api.jquery.com/click/) may help.

Comment: I don´t understand the people put negatives , i launch question for know if it´s possible do this in the experience of other people and the result all time with negatives ok very well, ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

You can understood what kind of events there are on the element,
this link help you :
[how to understand which events assigned to element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery/1236080#1236080)