# jQuery how to add a handler on a class but only if isn't already installed?

Tags: jquery, click, handler

I have a series of nodes I want to add a click handler to, the nodes will toggle an action, click once and something is set, click again and its cleared.

The problem is that the same handler is being installed more than once so a single click results in to calls to the handler.

How can I check if the handler is installed for the class and then only install if it isn't already installed?

I know there are similar posts to this already, however having read these I couldn't find one that solves my problem where I install then handler for the class.

[Edit], my code:

```
    //Need to detect is handler has already been installed before adding the handler below:
    $('.btnExpCol').click(function() {
    //Do something when any element with this class is clicked
    });
```

A lot of the comments are based around an 'id' which if you re-read my post, I am using a 'class' selector, however the issue has now been resolved and the solution works well.

[New code, which now works]:

```
    $('.btnExpCol').off("click").on("click", function() {
    //Do something when any element the has this class is clicked
    });
```

Comment: Numerous ways to approach this . Need more context. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Edit isn't detailed enough. Are the 2 handlers the same?

Comment: @charlietfl, the same code is called more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `unbinding` first and the `binding` it again

```
$("#id").unbind("click").bind("click",function(){...
```

prefer this (thanks to @charlietf)

```
$("#someid").off("click").on("click",function(){...
```

Comment: bind and unbind are deprecated , use `off()` and `on()`

Comment: yes i checked it is deprecated thanx @charlietfl. Then it is best to use on and off

Comment: I have implemented:  $('.btnExpCol').off("click").on("click", function() {  and this works ! Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches that might work.
1) Change the element when you install the handler (add a class) and use :not(.hashandler) when adding to ensure you don't add twice.

2) Don't do it. Instead just add one handler (ever) to the root, $(document).on('click','.myclass',function(){...});

Any "myclass" elements will run the function when clicked.

Comment: another simple approach is use `off()` then `on()`

Comment: The off and on technique removes and re-add the handlers - this is ok if they only exist once or twice in the DOM, but if you have a large DOM (we have a stadium seating plan where seats can be clicked) then adding and removing events in this way creates substantial overhead. In this case its better to only have one handler and you definitely don't want to take them off and on for every change - however, this is very usecase dependent.

Comment: actually better to delegate them once in that case

Comment: yep - we did do solution 2 for that use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would disable it with [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and then adding it again with [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

But if you want to go for it, this should give you an starting point:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Link</a>

$("#link").on("click", function(e){
    alert("link clicked");
});

$.each($._data($("#link")[0], "events"),function(i, v){
    if(v[0].type === "click") {
      alert("the click handler is set, do not add new");
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nygy1s9j/10/

Ideas taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery), tested with jquery 3.1.1