# How to check if the event listener is added already to window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i wanted to check if the event listener is already attached to the window using javascript or react.

what i am trying to do?

i have a dropdown menu component and in its didupdate hook cycle if the dropdown menu is open i add scroll event listener and on unmount hook cycle i remove the scroll event listener.

but in didupdate hook i add scroll event only if the condition this.props.open && !prevState.open is true....

but i dont remove the eventlistener scroll if this condition is false.

how can i do it....

below is the code,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.open && !prevState.open) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handle_scroll, {capture: true, passive: true});
    } else {
        //i want to remove scroll eventlistener here if its already added
    }
}

componentWillUnmount () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handle_scroll, {capture: true, passive: true});
}

handle_scroll = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.call_some_method);
};
```

What i have tried

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.open && !prevState.open) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handle_scroll, {capture: true, passive: true});
    } else {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handle_scroll, {capture: true, passive: true});
    }
}
```

But as seen from above code....it adds the scroll event listener only when the props.open && !prevState.open is true... and i remove the eventlistener when this is condition is false...and i want it to remove eventlistener when this.props.open && !prevState.open is false && scrollevent listener is added to window.

How can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Just set `state.listenerAdded` to `true` to keep track of it.

Comment: thanks but i dont want to use another state for this. could it be done without state.

Comment: Wait a sec, you're comparing props.open and state.open, are you sure that's right? Assuming this is a typo, you could simply reverse the condition: `else if (!this.props.open && prevState.open)`, which is the transition from "open" to "not open". (still: why not simply use state? it's a perfect fit here, since you want to keep track of... well... state)

Comment: ...copied the typo. Supposed to say `else if (!this.props.open && prevProps.open)`

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with jQuery ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery)) so it shouldn't be much trouble to transfer over to native JS.

> You can get this information from the data cache.
>
> For example, log them to the console (firebug, ie8):

```
console.dir( $('#someElementId').data('events') );
```

> or iterate them:

```
jQuery.each($('#someElementId').data('events'), function(i, event){

    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){

        console.log( handler.toString() );

    });

});
```

> Another way is you can use the following bookmarklet but obviously this does not help at runtime.